Definition of "discrimination"
I would like to ask about the definition of "discrimination". Is there's a general consensus on the definition? Which is/are it/they?.
I'll try to give a sensible definition: "Something is subject to discrimination by a group of people when those people believe, consciously or not, in factually wrong statistical implications of it". I'll give some examples of this definition in action.

"Many believe that taller people are more likely to be good volleyball players". This is not discriminating as when the only information we have is that someone is taller than average the odds favor him being a better than average volleyball player.
"Many believe that richer people are more likely to be happy". Supposing that a quantifiable definition of happy exists and that richer people aren't happier, this is a case of discrimination.

This definition gives no degree of positivity nor negativity to the term "discrimination". According to this definition non discriminating beliefs can be negative and discriminating beliefs can be positive. If something is good, bad, moral or immoral is not relevant in this definition. This is clearly not how the term "discrimination" is used colloquially, as it carries a strong negative connotation. (This question is about the negativity/positivity aspect but doesn't face the definition problem)

Wealth is indeed correlated with happiness. Anyway, "discrimination" already has statistical uses independent of positive/negative connotations, and not the use you give here. A discriminator is a classifier: a statistical model that assigns input examples into discrete classes. Outside of statistics, to have "discriminating" taste for food or art is a positive thing, meaning that you can tell what food or art is high quality. So what need do we have for your new definition?

I think it's strange to include "group of people" as a requirement for the people doing the discrimination, but not "group of people", or indeed, "people" at all as the subject of discrimination. For instance, it seems like if I, alone, believe something wrong about [class of people] that isn't discrimination. And likewise... we might say that "many people overestimate their chances of winning the lottery" is discrimination directed at "the lottery"?

I also wonder about whether "statistical implications" is always necessary. Suppose a group were to correctly understand all statistics and demographic information regarding race and how it intersects with all facets of society, but nonetheless thinks there should be racially segregated drinking fountains. It seems that the act of instituting that segregation is a discriminatory act, even if there is nothing factually wrong. (I am, I suppose, taking a position of moral anti-realism, or at least that moral facts are not statistical implications)

You seem to have conflated stereotyping with discrimination. Have you checked a dictionary? Google? Wikipedia? Those all give definitions, and they tend to reflect roughly the general consensus (among the general public, at least).

The question is not about my definition, altough you are welcome to discuss it, but about whether a definition exists. The definition I gave is only my personal try. By "group" I also mean a group of one person, I should have specified.

The word is ambiguous between at least two meanings, neutral (distinguishing) and morally loaded (disadvantage due to bias). It seems that you want to define a third. It is unclear to what end and how it is related to philosophy. That morally loaded discrimination is not necessarily morally wrong is acknowledged in the literature, see SEP, Discrimination.

@Kaia, I get the point you are making about the lottery. I should have said something like "Some personal characteristic is a reason of discrimination by a group of people when those people believe, consciously or not, in factually wrong statistical implications of it".

@NotThatGuy I'm talking about general consensus in philosophy and sociology.

Seems like the the kind of discrimination under discussion, the bad kind, would have to be something along the lines of unjustly making a decision that should be based on personal characteristics, on the basis of perceived group characteristics. Like, for example, not inviting an accountant to a party because accountants as a group are often thought (possibly correctly) to be boring. You should be asking whether this accountant would be boring, not whether accountants in general are likely to be boring.

That's not what the word means at all. Discrimination is being able to tell one thing from another. If I walk into the living room and sit on the couch and pet the cat, I've successfully discriminated between the two. Discriminating for or against some particular group is a special case.

I assume that you use the term in a sociological context. Taking racial discrimination as an example, the privileged race may discriminate but not the unprivileged. Similarly, in the socio-economic context, rich people cannot be discriminated against. The discrimination that you seem to refer to is an expression of power.
